# What is the way to handle Click on GWT FlowPanel

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom-events

May be a dumb question, but GWT FlowPanel (raw `div` element) does not provide something to handle a mouseclick/mousemovement on it. Overriding `onBrowserEvent` does not work either.

If setting `onclick` event using native JavaScript (need to specify positive height before, 'div' have a height of `0` if not specified), then catching these events is working properly. Is there a way to do it without using JSNI?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you need to do here is wrap your FlowPanel in a FocusPanel. A FocusPanel contain all possible handler and thus will enable you to have a ClickHandler set to it.

Another method would be to create your own widget extending the flowpanel and implementing the necessary interface in order to be able to contain a ClickHandler.

I personally would recommend the first method. It's simpler, faster to code and won't slow down your application.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, you go for this:

```
FlowPanel fPanel = new FlowPanel() {
      @Override
      public void onAttach() {
           super.onAttach();
           super.addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());  // handler is the instance         
                                                                // of your ClickHandler
      }
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Yes, it is a little bit hack-way but if a user is restricted with the FlowPanel usage, this trick can make a work for him. Thanks

Comment: If I could give this answer multiple upvotes I would.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me (Obviously, substitute "YOUR CLICKHANDLER" with your clickhandler's name) :

```
FlowPanel field = new FlowPanel();

field.addDomHandler(YOUR CLICKHANDLER, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I found for this was [here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/6973975200ef752a).

The idea is to extend the FlowPanel (or indeed SimplePanel) to implement the relevant handler interfaces, which is a much neater option for situations where you do not require the full functionality and focus capabilities of the FocusPanel. See below:

```
public class MouseAwareFlowPanel extends FlowPanel implements 
HasMouseOverHandlers, HasMouseOutHandlers, HasClickHandlers 
{ 
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseOverHandler(MouseOverHandler handler) 
    { 
        return addDomHandler(handler, MouseOverEvent.getType()); 
    } 
    public HandlerRegistration addMouseOutHandler(MouseOutHandler handler) 
    { 
        return addDomHandler(handler, MouseOutEvent.getType()); 
    } 
    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) 
    { 
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is also a good solution for those who don't want to receive all types of events! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems question is a dumb one, yes. `FlowPanel` can be easily wrapped or replaced with `FocusPanel`, which provides a lot of method for monitoring/handling events.

Comment: Well, if I understand FlowPanel and FocusPanel corrrectly, you can't replace FlowPanel by FocusPanel but you can sure wrap a FlowPanel in a FocusPanel.

Comment: Yes, `FocusPanel` is `SimplePanel` implementation, so it can not contain more than one child widget. But if your `FlowPanel` contains only one, you can simply replace it with `FocusPanel` :).

Comment: Well, using a FlowPanel for only 1 child would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the FlowPanel with a FocusPanel, that will leave ready the widget for other user interaction too:

**Source:**

```
    FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
    FocusPanel focusPanel = new FocusPanel(flowPanel);
    focusPanel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Window.alert("Hi!");
        }
    });
```